# How to execute shell script in RPM spec file?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have an RPM which includes to place files on the target machine. How can write shell script in such a way that if file already exists do not copy it.

Description:

When the RPM gets install it should not replace the file, if the file already exists in the location. Currently, it is changing the configuration as it is replacing. I am planning to write a conditional in the %install script section. I tried and it is not working, throwing error like "else"/"fi" not found.

Comment: what do you mean with "in specs folder" ? Try to be a little more precise in your question. Do you mean files that are in the %files section? What happens now if you install the rpms; what do you want to happen?

Comment: ah a "spec file" ; whole difference with "specs folder"... jeez

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. It was file :)

Comment: ok; i adapted my answer. If you really want scripts; look at the %pre and %post sections; NOT the %install section! But I strongly recommend looking into the %config(noreplace) directive in the %files section

Answer (score 3):

in the %files section of your spec file; you can mark your files with %config(noreplace) . That way if the file exists already on the target machine; it will not be overwritten (except if it was left untouched... see more details [here](http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/~jw35/docs/rpm_config.html)).

If you want to keep the existing file no matter what; then you can mess around in %pre and %post sections, but avoid that if you can... something like:

```
%pre
# gets executed before installation of the files: 
if [ -e /path/to/file]
then
    cp /path/to/file /path/to/backup
fi

%post
# gets executed after installatin of the files
if [ -e /path/to/file]
then
    cp /path/to/backup /path/to/file
fi
```

Comment: does %pre section gets execute before %prep section?

Comment: you're confused about how an rpm works... when BUILDING an rpm; the %prep, %install, %files and %changelog sections are used to produce a *.rpm file. When you INSTALL this rpm; the %pre section is executed on the machine where the rpm is installed; then the files (from the %files section) are put in place; and then the %post section is installed.

Comment: normally BUILDING and INSTALLING happen on different machines!